# Markdown list indentation with 3 spaces or 4 spaces? What is the standard?

Tags: markdown

I have googled this for hours. But different people give different answers. Some people say 4 spaces is the standard and some people say 3 spaces is the standard for markdown. I am very confused. Can anyone please simply tell me what is the recommended standard? Thanks.

- how many spaces

  - should I use

    - here?

I know 2 spaces, 3 spaces and 4 spaces are all working. But I just want to know what the formal standard is. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest thing markdown has to a standard is CommonMark, which has a [list definition](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#list-items) that allows:

> a list marker of width W followed by 1 ≤ N ≤ 4 spaces

For unordered lists, I've seen most people to use two spaces. But it's really personal preference.

```
- foo
  - bar
```

In CommonMark, you have to indent at least as much as the first character that's not part of the list marker and not whitespace (i.e. the `f` in the above example).

So for ordered lists, you have to indent at least three, so most people go with four, which also works when you hit the list marker `10.`

```
 9. foo
10. foo
    1. bar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have marked it as the answer. Btw, one more question, I always use `1.` only for ordered lists. such as `1. foo 1. foo 1. foo`, is this not recommended? Since the numbering is auto-generated, I don't bother to give it manually. If I give it manually and want to insert some items, I have to re-order everything. If I only use `1.`, I think I can just use three spaces for both ordered lists and unordered lists, right? Four spaces look too much to me. and I also want to make the spaces identical as possible for both list types. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's all fine. Ultimately, it's up to you to come up with some kind of style guide. Always using `1.` makes the markdown somewhat less readable, but yes... more editable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I don't like `Tab`. I feel 4 spaces are too much to be used. 2 spaces do not work with ordered list. To make both list types identical, the only option left for me is 3 spaces... But I do feel 3 spaces is weird too..

Comment: I think it is compulsory the use of (at least) 2 spaces. _The rules for sublists follow from the general rules above. A sublist must be indented the same number of spaces of indentation a paragraph would need to be in order to be included in the list item. So, in this case we need two spaces indent._